# Why does an object loose its polymorphic nature when pushed into a container?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

An object `child` derived from `base`

```
class base
{
    public:
    virtual int get() const { return 0;}
    ~virtual base(){}
    };

    class child : public base
    {
    public:
    virtual int get() const override { return 1; }
};
```

is sliced when added to a container e.g.

```
std::vector<base> bases;
bases.push_back(child());
```

and the code below returns 0

```
bases.at(0).get();
```

Even if the signature of push_back is:

```
void push_back( const T& value );
void push_back( T && value );
```

which shouldn't incur the object to be sliced.

For example the code below results in bad_cast

```
dynamic_cast<child &>(bases.at(0))
```

Whereas calling with child of base exhibits polymorphic behaviour

```
void toto(base const & e)
{
    std::cout << e.get() << std::endl;
}
```

which implies the object is not anymore a child; where did it get sliced? what does actually happen?

Would it be possible to setup`base` or `child` such that is copes with being placed in the container and the object does not lose its polymorphic nature?

**This is a rationale question, and it is already known that an object is copied, so please do not to suggest pointers/shared_ptr as this has been addressed elsewhere.**

Comment: "such that is copes with being placed in the container " please explain what you mean.

Comment: If you already *know* that an object is copied when passed to this vector, and the solution is to use pointers to retain polymorphic behaviour - I don't understand the point of this question - there is no way to retain this behaviour without pointers - this is C++

Comment: @Nim That's true in other languages as well.

Comment: @Nim certainly, if it is not possible, then answer with rationale that this is not possible, and that is a valid answer . Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> where did it get sliced?

Your

```
std::vector<base> bases;
```

stores plain `base` objects. You just can not add anything else there, only a `base` objects. So if ever you get an object added there, it will be a `base` object. If you passed another type to `push_back`, it will be converted to `base` (if possible); in your case this means sliced. I do not think that you are interested at where exactly does the slicing occur inside `std::vector`'s functions of a specific implementation.

> Would it be possible to setup `base` or `child` such that is copes with
>   being placed in the container and the object does not lose it's
>   polymorphic nature?

To keep polymorphic nature, you need to store pointers to `base`s<sup>1</sup>. And there are many ways to make it copy on addition to the container. The simplest way is to write something like

```
child c;
...
std::vector<base*> v;
v.push_back(new child(c)); // and yes, smart pointers are better
```

You may of course add wrappers for the `push_back` to avoid typing `new` each time.

<sup>1 You can not store references in the vector, but consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488326/c-stdvector-of-references) for more options.</sup>

Comment: @Nim, oh yes, my bad.

Comment: @Nim You _can_ store references in the form of `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @zenith, sure - but that's cheating.. ;) (as it's internally storing a pointer anyway.. )

Comment: The template parameter does not always tell you what happens in the class, so just saying that it is parametrized by base, does not tell much. Of course the same can be said about the signature of push_back. However let me remind that there is a signature also that moves the object into push_back. All these are a bit surprising to the inconspicuous.

Answer (score 3):

> Even if the signature of push_back is:
>
> which shouldn't incur the object to be sliced.

This is true.

> For example the code below results in bad_cast
>   `dynamic_cast<child &>(bases.at(0))`

Yes, it does. And `dynamic_cast` is not in `std::`.

> Whereas calling with child of base exhibits polymorphic behaviour
>
> ```
> void toto(base const & e)
> {
> std::cout << e.get() << std::endl;
> }
> ```

Yes, it does.

> where did it get sliced? what does actually happen?

The problem is not `push_back` per se. **Slicing** happens when `push_back` *assigns* what you passed to the internal object, **which is not polymorphic**, not when the parameter itself is bound.

To keep the polymorphic behavior you must use either pointers (preferably smart pointers) or references; however, plain references cannot be stored in a container and you have to use a wrapper for them like `std::reference_wrapper`.

[There is a very comprehensive (and imho underrated) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references) from Stephen Li about why polymorphism works this way.

Comment: Thanks for your edits, I have accepted most, and have not actually seen the std in dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 2):

This can not work: Polymorphism uses VTables which stores pointers to the methods of you class. The problem: If you copy it, the VTable pointers will be set to the base class adresses.

Additionally it can not work because the derived class can be bigger as the base class so the memory consumption can not be calculated. But a container need to know how big the objects are.