# Should a std::vector of objects use pointers, references, or nothing?

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose we have some class, say `class Apple`, and wanted to store a `std::vector` containing `Apple`.

Should the vector contain pointers, references, or plain objects?

```
std::vector<Apple*> vector; // Definitely won't copy the Apple on lookup, 
    // but I would prefer not to use pointers if I don't have to
std::vector<Apple&> vector; // Seems circuitous?
std::vector<Apple> vector; // I don't know if this copies the Apple on each lookup
```

My goal is to make it so when I call

```
Apple& a = vector[4];
```

the `Apple` won't get copied.

I've been using C++ for over a year and I've always worked around this and never understood it. Is there a simple explanation of why one of these three approaches is the best practice?

Comment: I'll ask a question back: who shall *own* the objects you can access by index? The vector? Or will the vector *point* or *reference* to another actual owner?

Comment: Also, is Apple polymorphic?

Comment: Zeta: good question, the vector is going to own the objects.

Comment: HolyBlackCat: that's a good question, Apple is not polymorphic. But if it was, we'd definitely want to use a pointer, right?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I think so. They sell hardware and software. <g>

Comment: If it was polymorphic, I'd suggest figure out how to make a copyable `unique_ptr` wrapper (using type erasure) and use that. If it sounds too hard, use pointers.

Comment: In this case the template class is not polymorphic, but in the future when it is, I'll definitely use the smart pointer wrapper!

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use it. If there was only one answer there would be only one way.

Comment: `std::vector` was designed with a whole-part semantics in mind, i.e., assuming the container should own its elements. If `Apple` is not run-time polymorphic, then `std::vector<Apple>` is the best choice.

Comment: At a meta-level, it depends on whether Apple is a value object, or an identity object, or a service object.  And it also depends on what owns Apple.  Does the vector own Apple?  Does the vector just refer to an extant Apple?  What is the lifecycle and lifetime of an Apple?

Comment: What is your real concern here about the copy? Performance? If `Apple` is a struct of three integers, please stop concerning yourself with performance and copy away.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23488449/186997 may add some criteria to help you decide (shameless plug).

Comment: Best practice for what? How are you going to use the vector?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the type `T`. Remember that `operator[]` returns a (const) reference, so your `Apple&` works fine there:

```
      T& vector<T>::operator[](size_t);
const T& vector<T>::operator[](size_t) const;
```

That's why you can use `vec[3].make_older()` to begin with if `return_type Apple::make_older(void)` exists.

However, keep in mind that there are *many* methods that invalidate references, so

```
Apple& reference = vec[3];
vec.push_back(other_apple);

reference.get_eaten();
```

might result in undefined behaviour if `push_back` reallocated the referenced apple.

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
std::vector<Apple> vector; // I don't know if this copies the Apple on each lookup
```

While all of them would achieve your goal (a lookup never copies), this is the one that allows the `vector` to own the `Apple`s in it so that the lifetimes are sensibly managed.

Comment: Note that not all of them work. A vector of references is not allowed.

Comment: @Rakete1111, A vector of references is not allowed but a vector of [`reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) does work.

Comment: @Vassilis Jup, but a `reference_wrapper` is not a reference :)